# Jquery datatables format numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the latest Datatables plugin 1.10 version.

I have 3 columns (0 , 1, 2).
Columns 1 and 2 contain numbers which should be formatted like:

```
1000 -> 1.000
10000 -> 10.000
```

I searched the documentation and I found these relevant functions:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/formatNumber

https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.thousands

Are the columns that need to be formatted detected automatically?

What is the correct usage of the above functions?

Comment: you should use regex inside `mRender` on your `targets[2]` and format the number respectively with regex and bind it to table depending on your requirement . ex: "render":  function(data) {//return formatted value;} },

Comment: @supercool this works. u can write an answer to mark as accepted

Comment: @gosom What regex did you use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you have to do something like this

**Inside Datatable initialization** :

```
 "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": [ 2 ],
    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
     var formmatedvalue=data.replace(//regex expression)
      return formmatedvalue;
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 41):

There is actually an even easier way to do this, also found on the datatables documentation:

```
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ReceiptQuantity", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '') },
            { "data": "ReceiptPrice", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '') },
            { "data": "LineTotal", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '') }
        ],
```

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Built-in-helpers. I was having some difficulty locating this, so thought the link might help others.

Comment: Filter initialization crashes and i recieve `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`.

Comment: Perfect. It's fine for me this solution :)

Comment: It works, also the ordering by column works after number formatting.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#table-dg').dataTable({
    "columns": columnNames,
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                 return commaSeparateNumber(data);
            },
            "targets": [1,2]
        },
    ]
});

function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When answering questions, it's best to add a description to the answer code you have provided.

Comment: It works for formatting numbers but it brokes the ordering by column: all values will be ordered in a wrong order. @JustLearning's answer works for me.