# Formatting numbers using DataTables breaks sorting

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a tables that I am trying to sort, the problem is that when I add locales to the numbers, it breaks sorting, it sorts as it were strings.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380390/jquery-datatables-format-numbers) answer and I modified without having to use regex, but then it begins sorting as it were strings and no longer numbers, for instance

```
1
1.200
2
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_table').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bShowPollInfo": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "aLengthMenu": [[20, 40, -1], [20, 40, "_all"]],
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "160px", "sClass": "nowrap" },
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
               "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                   return formatNumbers(data);
               },
               "aTargets": [1, 2]
            },
        ],
    });
});
function formatNumbers(val) {
    return parseInt(val).toLocaleString("de-DE");
}
```

Comment: Your `formatNumbers()` function *explicitly* returns a string; what did you expect to happen? Also, if you really have numbers with fractional parts, you should not be using `parseInt()` on the values. (If they start out as numbers, then you don't need to "parse" them at all anyway.)

Comment: Is there any way to add locale without breaking the sort?

Comment: [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `"aoColumnDefs"` part to this

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {
       "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
            if( type === 'display' ){
                return formatNumbers(data); // only format the data for display
            }else{
                return data; // the default data should be used for sorting
            }
       },
       "aTargets": [1, 2]
    },
],
```